# Cleaning LexisNexis txt file, ZeroDivisionError

Tags: python, csv, text, jupyter

I'm trying to clean some NexisLexis news data using Neal Caren's Python script. However, when I do try to run it, this specific line gives me a ZeroDivisionError:

```
meta_list=[m for m in meta_list if float(lnraw.count(m))/(len(workfile)>.20)]
```

With the     workfile being:

```
workfile=re.sub('                Copyright .*?\\r\\n','ENDOFILE',lnraw) 
workfile=workfile.replace('\xef\xbb\xbf\r\n','')
workfile=workfile.split('ENDOFILE')
workfile=[f for f in workfile if len(f.split('\r\n\r\n'))>2]
```

I cannot seem to fix it, the non-zero condition does seem to be met with the >.20?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`(len(workfile)>.20)` is either `True` or `False`

`X/False` => `ZeroDevisionError`

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! How would you incorporate this? 
Something like this? 
    if len(workfile)>.20 is True: